# Bitmask and -offset by offset and length

Tags: c#, .net, bit-manipulation, bit-shift

I want to create a bitmask and the bitmask offset by offset and length.

For example:
`offset = 8` and 
`length = 4`

the bitmask should be: 0xF00 = 3840 in decimal(1111.0000.0000)

and the bitoffset should be: 0x100 = 256 in decimal

I've tried the following, but that's wrong:

```
ulong mask = 0;
for (int i = 0; i < offset; i++)
{
    mask += (1 << 1) | 0;
}
```

How can I do that?

Comment: Offset defines when the first `1` begin and length is a number of `1` until `0` or what?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

One way might be something like:

```
ulong mask = ((1 << length) - 1) << offset;
```

I'm not clear why you even want the `bitoffset` value, but that should simply be a matter of shifting by your `offset` value, right? E.g.:

```
ulong bitoffset = 1 << offset;
```